# What pattern or architecture should I implement by Laravel to structure this project?

Tags: laravel, web, design-patterns, architecture, structure

The project is simple, and it has to do with formula 1 statistics. The UI looks a lot like a game menu. Going from "option" to "option" in the UI you end up in an "endpoint" page where the user can see the statistics of his like. It's tree structure where every "option" is a separate view on my project.

The user click "Race standings" to load a page. The user click a year on a form to see next page. The user click a race of that year then redirects to "race result" page. The logic for doing this is to create a nice UI so the user would like to spend time on the site and navigate through the pages.

I POST data from my view's forms to a controller's function. This function fetch the data from the database using my models and the post parameters, do the logic and return('thatView', compact('array' , 'array2', 'etc). php and javascript on the views manipulates the organized arrays fitting them into html. Arrays contains text data, for example array 1 could be the data of a race-result table.

The way my project is structure is very amateur. No patterns, no architecture, no anything good. Using directly the raceresult domain on the browser will result error. The needed parameters are missing as they cannot be set from the domain, it needs the previous page to post the data.

How could i structure my project better? What patterns could i use?

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic overview you can follow:

App
-- Repositories
-- Services

Route > Controller > Service > Repository

Controller's method calls Service method. Here you put your business rules. If there as need of calling database, use repositories to do that.

It's clear for you?